# In some cases I get Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty

Tags: php

I am trying to upload images to imgur and I can upload most of the images but there are some images that I am not able to upload and I have no idea why. It gives me warning.

> Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\wamp64\www\social\my-account.php

if there is something wrong with the code how am I able to upload other images of same file type.

From what I have observed all the pictures that failed to upload, the file size was quite large (approx in 2MB-4MB).

If this is because of size how can I fix this problem.

```
<h1>My account</h1>
<form action="my-account.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Upload an image...
    <input type="file" name="profileimg">
    <input type="submit" name="uploadprofileimg" value="Upload Image">


</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['uploadprofileimg']))
{
    $image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["profileimg"]["tmp_name"]));

    $options = array('http'=>array(
                'method'=>"POST",
                'header'=>
                "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n".
                "Authorization: Bearer 82afc16954948508dfcf37e0a899759f34ab26c2\n",
                'content' =>$image
    ));
    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    print_r($_FILES);


    $imgurURL = "https://api.imgur.com/3/image";
    $response = file_get_contents($imgurURL, false, $context);



}

?>
```

Output of print_r() :

```
Array ( [profileimg] => Array ( [name] => pexels-photo-374710.jpeg [type] => 
[tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 ))
```

Link to some images that I was not able to upload :
[Images that failed to upload](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wGWBlJ6Cf_jcVVkxSh3vEoj23F0GZjyj)

Comment: you may need to check the php config for file uploads (see http://php.net/manual/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize and http://php.net/manual/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size ) if this error occurs only with large files. Also, have a look at file upload errors (see http://php.net/manual/features.file-upload.errors.php ) you will get usefull information on what happened

Comment: the error value `1` in your print_r means that the file is bigger than the configured value of the php.ini

Comment: If you `echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize');` what does that tell you?

Comment: It says 2M. So the maximum size of file can only be upto 2MB

Comment: No you have to increase the `upload_max_filesize` either in your `php.ini` file

Comment: Okay, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the output you gave for the failed upload and by looking at the documentation on file upload errors ( http://php.net/manual/features.file-upload.errors.php ) the value `"1"` in `$_FILES['profileimg']['error']` translates to `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE`

from the doc :

> **`UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE` Value: `1`**; The uploaded file exceeds the `upload_max_filesize` directive in php.ini.

So you have to change the configuration in your php.ini and increase the [`upload_max_filesize`](http://php.net/manual/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) and the [`post_max_size`](http://php.net/manual/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) to get the upload working for this image.

Also note that it is a good practice to always check if the upload was successfull (`$_FILES['profileimg']['error'] = 0`) before trying to process the file.